# ListView very slow when scrolling

Tags: android, performance, listview

I really need help, Listview which I used in my app is very slow while scrolling  how can I fix it ? I reduce the images, use viewholder but nothing change..

I am beginner in android : )

also get this message : I/Choreographer: Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Here is my code

```
public class asker extends Activity {
    ListView list;
    String[] askerbaslik;
    int[] images =

            {R.drawable.barbar_icon, R.drawable.okcu_icon,
                    R.drawable.dev_icon,
                    R.drawable.goblin_icon,
                    R.drawable.duvar_kirici_icon, R.drawable.balon_icon,
                    R.drawable.buyucu_icon, R.drawable.sifaci_icon,
                    R.drawable.ejderha_icon,
                    R.drawable.pekka_icon, R.drawable.yavruejder_icon, R.drawable.madenci_icon};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview);

        Resources res = getResources();
        askerbaslik = res.getStringArray(R.array.asker_adlari);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        ilyasadapter adapter = new ilyasadapter(this, askerbaslik, images);

        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ilyasadapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        Context context;
        int[] images;
        String[] titlearray;

        ilyasadapter(Context c, String[] titles, int imgs[]) {
            super(c, R.layout.liste_tasarim, R.id.asker_baslik, titles);
            this.context = c;
            this.images = imgs;
            this.titlearray = titles;
        }

        class MyViewHolder {
            TextView mytitle;
            ImageView myimage;

            MyViewHolder(View v) {

                mytitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.asker_baslik);
                myimage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.asker_icon);
            }
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            MyViewHolder holder = null;

            if (row == null) {

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                        context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.liste_tasarim, parent, false);
                holder = new MyViewHolder(row);

                row.setTag(holder);

                Log.d("test", "creating a new row");
            } else {

                holder = (MyViewHolder) row.getTag();

                Log.d("test", "Recycling stuff");
            }

            holder.myimage.setImageResource(images[position]);
            holder.mytitle.setText(titlearray[position]);

            return row;
        }
    }
}
```

Single row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ImageView
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/asker_icon"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/barbar_icon"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"

    ></ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/asker_baslik"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Asker ismi"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    />

  </LinearLayout>
```

my listview

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#455A64" >
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="#263238"
    android:dividerHeight="2px"
    />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you done any profiling to determine where the load is becoming heavy enough for it to slow down the listview performance?

Comment: Just a thought, but try removing the images from the listview item to see if that is where the bottleneck is.  Are the images really large res?

Comment: I'm just wondering why do you have layout_height="match_parent" in your single row shouldn't it be wrap_content

Comment: Thank you for answers.   Yesterday, I compressed the images which is 6 mb to reduce 3 .7 mb. after that I learn from here to change image sizes to 100px  then  again app reduce 3.7 mb to 1.7 mb which is work very very fast. thank you for supporting guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to remove the icons from the listview and see if that improves performance. You may be using images with too high of a resolution. I too have noticed [performance anomalies](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/issues/1576) when using high-resolution images.

Let me know if that helps. If not, there are a few other things that we can try.

Comment: thank you . I change the image sizes then its work perfect now!!

Comment: @Boyka I'm glad to hear it! Please "accept" my answer so that people will see that you got the problem resolved.